# Display number of hours since a specific time in bash

Tags: bash, scripts, date

I have a command that outputs a single date in whatever format I please. Now I need a simple way of calculating (with bash) how many hours have passed since that date (default is `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm`).

The only way I can think of doing this is by using several `if`s, but I was hoping there might be a quick one-line method. Perhaps using the `date` command?

Just an example for clarity:
Right now it is `2011-05-23 12:16`.
The first command outputs `2011-05-22 08:34`.
I need a command (or a few piped commands) that output `27`, as in: "27 hours (rounded down) have passed since the specified date".

Is there a quick'n simple way to achieve that? Or am I bound to use conditionals (not that it'd be overly complex).

Comment: http://www.unix.com/tips-tutorials/31944-simple-date-time-calulation-bash.html this is a small script regarding subtracting dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking for times in Unix it's simplest to convert both datetimes into [Unix Timestamps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (that are seconds since 1970-1-1 00:00), subtract one from other and, in your case, divide by 3600 to get the hours.

```
SECONDS=`expr $(date -d "20110523" +%s) - $(date -d "20110522" +%s)`
expr $SECONDS / 3600

#Return is 24
```

Comment: Perfect! Didn't know about Unix Timestamps.

Comment: That's right for about a second. `SECONDS` is a special bash variable that changes every second. Also, bash can do integer math; no need for expr.